# Working with Shared Folders & Files on Mac

Tags: mac, folders, sharing, file-sharing, invisible-files

I use shared folders on different computers for work. All mac machines. I pull folders from the shared folders. I do the work that needs to be done. Then I drop the work back into the shared folder so others can get to them. Most of the time it works fine. There’s no problem. When there a problem is the work files act as if the are locked. All permissions are set to all read and write with all the enclosed items unlocked too. Neither users can retrieve the work files. Or they completely disappear when dropping them in. What’s going on?

All the general work arounds doesn’t seem to help in regards to shared folders. Hope for some suggestions from anyone that may have experienced this problem before.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit more info might help: what error messages do you get? Can you provide detailed terminal listing of the files' attributes? Is this a business setup?

Comment: What error messages do I get? 

The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items. 

And then the longer version as to why I don’t have permission.  
 
—— 
Right now I am working IN the shared folder.  I created the work files in the shared folder. Everything works as it should. I delete what I don’t want once done. Even though I had just created the file and or folder that I then delete gives me the message about permissions. The folder updates but shows nothing. That’s why I delete to start over. 

This is a business setup.

Comment: The message is: the operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. From each item, Choose File, Get Info, make sure “Locked” and not designated as Read Only or No Access, try again. 

This message comes from updating work files and folders in and out the shared folder. Doesn’t seem to matter which I work from.

Comment: The designations are set as Read & Write.

Comment: Folders and files are unlocked when I get to them. Overtime they lock again. Is there a way to prevent locking permanently? I understand that Apple locks things for security reasons.

Comment: How are the different user accounts managed on the server? Realistically, this problem needs hands-on scrutiny, looking at the entire server setup, networking, and clients. As a business, if your IT staff can't fix it, you need to pay to get someone to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Manually moving files in this way might not be the best way of working, and may be the root of your problems. Are the files on the server set to allow EVERYONE to read and write?

Either use one Mac as a server and open the files directly from there; or synchronise local copies of the files on multiple Macs.

This is really where using a NAS or Cloud storage comes into its own.

Comment: Files on the server are set to allow everyone to read and write. 

One Mac is designated as a server. Working on the server, permissions lock even after just making a folder to drop files in.